# How to include enum in Swift 4 JSON decoding?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift4

The receives the message from backend and now I want to use the swift 4 JSON decoding. I tested it with an object with regular properties (String, Int, ...) and I worked without a problem. Now I want to handle the object which have a enum property which I want to be set when the initialization of object happens. How to setup initialization so it will include setting enum?

```
struct WebPacket: Decodable {
  let type: MessageType
  let message: String

  init(with type: MessageType, data: Data) {
    type = type
    // fill others
  }
}

enum MessageType: String {
  case unknown
  case getDescription     = "get-daa-description"
  case description        = "daa-description"
  case holdings           = "holdings"
}
```

Comment: sorry, i fixed it. this init function is just an improvisation of what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Since `MessageType` got a JSON compliant raw value, just adopt `Decodable`

```
enum MessageType: String, Decodable {
    case unknown
    case getDescription     = "get-daa-description"
    case description        = "daa-description"
    case holdings           = "holdings"
}

struct WebPacket : Decodable {
    let type : MessageType
    let message : String
}

let jsonString = "{\"type\": \"daa-description\", \"message\" : \"Hello World\"}"

let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebPacket.self, from: jsonData)
    print("decoded:", decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: `jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!` can be simplified and no need to force unwrap (which in this case is not a problem because it will never crash) to `Data(jsonString.utf8)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Wow, that's really cool, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. This is only possible since Swift 3 because Data conforms to collection

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

```
struct WebPacket: Decodable {
    var type: MessageType

    init(with type: MessageType, data: Data) {
        self.type = type
    }
}

enum MessageType: String, Decodable { // Here I just added Decodable
    case unknown
    case getDescription     = "get-daa-description"
    case description        = "daa-description"
    case holdings           = "holdings"
}

let json = """
    [
        {
            "type": "get-daa-description"
        },    
        {
            "type": "daa-description"
        },
        {
            "type": "holdings"
        }
    ]
"""

do {
    let webPacket = try JSONDecoder().decode([WebPacket].self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    for i in 0..<webPacket.count {
        print(webPacket[i].type.rawValue)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```